# Почему-то не работает, бот включается, но банворды не удаляет

Tags: python, discord

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot {bot.user} is ready to work!")


with open('bun_words.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    kek = file.read()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for content in message.content.split():
        for censored_word in kek:
            if content == censored_word:
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} такие слова запрещены!")


@bot.event
async def on_commands_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)

bot.run()
```

Comment: Для начала попробуйте `file.read()` -> `file.read().split()`, затем `if content.lower() == censored_word.lower():`, а вообще это проще делается, чем цикл в цикле, но для начала вам хватит. А так в любой ситуации нужно печатать или логировать переменные, тогда вы сами сможете разобраться. Если бы вы знали, чему у вас равно `censored_word`, например, вы бы сами поняли, что здесь не так.

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать метод readlines() чтобы построчно грузить файл

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot {bot.user} is ready to work!")


with open('bun_words.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    kek = [word.strip() for word in file.readlines()]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for content in message.content.split():
        for censored_word in kek:
            if content == censored_word:
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} такие слова запрещены!")


@bot.event
async def on_commands_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)

bot.run()
```